# using kapacitor with influxdb and collectd

Tags: collectd, kapacitor

I'm trying to integrate Kapacitor with our influxdb and collectd setup. However, It doesn't seem to work, and I don't understand why.

Collectd and Influxdb are running correctly, and I think Kapacitor is able to connect to influxdb. In the kapacitor log I see this:

```
[influxdb] 2016/04/22 09:46:42 I! started UDP listener for collectd_db default
```

This is the name of the influxdb database where collectd is recording metrics.

I created the following tick-file, and uploaded it to kapacitor and enabled it:

```
stream
    .from().measurement('cpu_value')
    .where(lambda: "type" == "percent")
    .where(lambda: "type_instance" == "idle")
    .alert()
        .crit(lambda: "value" <  100)
        // Whenever we get an alert write it to a file.
        .log('/tmp/alerts.log')
```

This was just a test script, which hopefully produces some output.

The script is enabled:

```
Name                          Type      Enabled   Executing Databases and Retention Policies
cpu_tick                      stream    true      true      ["collectd_db"."default"]
```

However, I don't see any recordings:

```
[centos@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx tmp]$ kapacitor list recordings
ID                                      Type    Size      Created
```

"cpu_value" is a valid measurement in my database.

This is what I get in my error log:

```
[cpu_alert:stream1] 2016/04/28 13:00:51 E! error while evaluating WHERE expression: name "percent" is undefined. Names in scope: time,value,host,instance,type,type_instance
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author of Kapacitor here...

In Kapacitor lambda expressions single quotes vs double quotes have different meanings.

- Single quotes indicate a string literal
- Double quotes are a reference to a field or tag from the data.

This expression `.where(lambda: "type" == "percent")` is saying only keep data points who's `type` field or tag value is equal to the value of the `percent` field or tag. As per the err

> [cpu_alert:stream1] 2016/04/28 13:00:51 E! error while evaluating WHERE expression: name "percent" is undefined. Names in scope: time,value,host,instance,type,type_instance

The `percent` field or tag does not exist.

You need to use single quotes if you want to filter points who's type value is equal to the `percent` literal.

`.where(lambda: "type" == 'percent')`

The same is probably true for your next expression as well.

`.where(lambda: "type_instance" == 'idle')`

Also you can `AND` expressions together if you wish

`.where(lambda: "type" == 'percent' AND "type_instance" == 'idle')`

When Kapacitor finds multiple `where` statements adjacent it converts them to an And'ed expression under the hood.

Here is relevant docs explaining the quotes differences https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v0.12/introduction/getting_started/#keep-the-quotes-in-mind

As for why there are no recordings I cannot answer without more context as to how you tried to create a recording.