# Using collectd and kapacitor - not triggering alerts

Tags: collectd, kapacitor

I am trying to get kapacitor to trigger an alert based on collectd data in influxdb. Am basing my tick file on the answer in [using kapacitor with influxdb and collectd](https://serverfault.com/questions/773565/using-kapacitor-with-influxdb-and-collectd).

```
stream
// Select just the cpu measurement from our example database.
|from()
    .measurement('cpu_value')
    .where(lambda: "type" == 'percent' AND "type_instance" == 'idle')
|alert()
    .crit(lambda: "value" <  98)
    // Whenever we get an alert write it to a file.
    .log('/tmp/alerts.log')
```

I have defined the alert as per kapacitor docs:

```
kapacitor define cpu_alert -type stream -tick cpu_alert.tick -dbrp collectd.default
```

Appropriate data is being sent to influxdb from collectd and available via query:

```
select value from /cpu_value/ where type='percent' and type_instance = 'idle' order by time desc limit 10;
```

[image]

However running :

```
kapacitor record stream -task cpu_alert -duration 20s &
```

does not record any data:

```
$ kapacitor list recordings
ID                                      Type    Status    Size      Date                   
48e5c04a-68c2-44a3-ba80-f2c12d952994    stream  running   0 B       19    Jul 16 11:57 IST
```

I *suspect* that I may not be correctly referencing the database when I register the task, but cannot see where I have an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause was incorrect configuration. Pay attention to the "influxdb.subscriptions" and "influxdb.excluded-subscriptions" sections of the kapacitor.conf file.

By default kapacitor subscribes to all Influx DBs. I wanted it only to subscribe to one DB, but erroneously included this in the "influxdb.excluded-subscriptions" section rather than the "influxdb.subscriptions".

You can see what subscriptions are active by issuing a "SHOW SUBSCRIPTIONS" query to influxdb.